# Why won't my global variable update after this function is called in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

My global variable isn't changing after the function is called in Node.js when I run the application in Sublime Text 3. When I run it in bash, it changes as expected. When I replace "global.firstname = 'David'" with "window.firstname = 'David'" and run it in chrome's console, it changes as expected.

```
var firstname = 'Simon';

var addSurname = function(){

    var firstname = 'Gene';
    var surname = 'Holmes';
    var fullname = firstname + ' ' + surname;
    global.firstname = 'David';
    console.log(fullname);
};

addSurname();
console.log(firstname);

// Gene Holmes
// Simon
```

Ultimately, I want it to output

```
// Gene Holmes
// David
```

Why isn't the "global.firstname='David'" statement updating my global variable with the Node.js build in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: In node.js the global object does not have a name. It is not "global" and it is not "window". There literally is no variable available that point to the global object. The only way to access the global object directly is using `this` trickery but that does not work in strict mode. Fortunately you don't need to access the global object to work with global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a global var in a function you just need to define it as global with `var` keyword then use the same var name after the alteration of this var inside a function it is saved back in global var. So you don't need the use of `global.` or something like this.

```
var firstname = 'Simon';

var addSurname = function(){

    var firstnameTmp = 'Gene';
    var surname = 'Holmes';
    var fullname = firstnameTmp + ' ' + surname;
    firstname = 'David';
    console.log(fullname);
};

addSurname();
console.log(firstname);// Will output David.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use 2 variables with the same name?

```js
var firstname = 'Simon';

var addSurname = function(){

    var firstname2 = 'Gene';
    var surname = 'Holmes';
    var fullname = firstname2 + ' ' + surname;
    firstname = 'David';
    console.log(fullname);
};

addSurname();
console.log(firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstname = 'Simon';

var addSurname = function(){

    var firstname2 = 'Gene';
    var surname = 'Holmes';
    var fullname = firstname2 + ' ' + surname;
    firstname = 'David';
    console.log(fullname);
};

addSurname();
console.log(firstname);
```